# Bash script sftp only downloading files to same directory script is in

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sftp

I have a weird problem. I am trying to download a file from a ftp server to a different directory than what the bash script is running. If I do it manually everything works fine. I can connect type

`get sampleFile.csv /path/to/directory/`

Trying to put that in a bash script doesn't work. I get all the same output as doing it manaully

`/ftp/sampleFile.csv 100%  384     0.4KB/s   00:01`

but the file isn't in the directory or anywhere that I can find on my server. I have tried

```
sftp ***** << EOF
get sampleFile.csv /path/to/directory/
quit
EOF
```

and

```
cd /path/to/directory/
sftp ***** << EOF
get sampleFile.csv
quit
EOF
```

and

```
sftp ***** << EOF
lcd /path/to/directory
get sampleFile.csv
quit
EOF
```

All of these work doing it manually.

The only thing that works is

```
sftp ***** << EOF
get sampleFile.csv
quit
EOF
```

This puts the file in the same directory the bash script is in and it shows up. Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: Try using the `-b` option, e.g.

-b batchfile
             Batch mode reads a series of commands from an input batchfile
             instead of stdin.  Since it lacks user interaction it should be
             used in conjunction with non-interactive authentication to
             obviate the need to enter a password at connection time (see
             sshd(8) and ssh-keygen(1) for details).
             Termination on error can be suppressed on a command by command
             basis by prefixing the command with a ‘-’ character (for example, -rm /tmp/blah*).

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the weird problem you described. Try adding `pwd` and `lpwd` commands before your `get ...` to see if they provide any clues.